# How to JNDI lookup from cluster 1 : a queue that exists in cluster 2 in Websphere 6?

Tags: websphere, cluster-computing, jndi, lookup

I have a Websphere topology wherein in Cluster1, I have an MDB that's trying to publish to another MDB that resides in Cluster2. Since they're both in the same container, I tried simply

> Blockquote
>   Context ctx = new InitialContext();
>   ctx.lookup("jms/MyQueue");
>   Blockquote

The "jms/MyQueue" is configured in Cluster2. As you can see, this doesn't work!! 
1) Do I have to provide an environment entry  while creating the InitialContext? Even though both clusters are part of the same container?
2) If not, how then can I lookup the said queue in Cluster 2?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a cell-scoped queue resource rather than a cluster-scoped queue resource.  To answer the specific questions:

> 1) Do I have to provide an environment
>   entry while creating the
>   InitialContext?

No, if the clusters are part of the same cell.  Otherwise, you need to [specify an alternate PROVIDER_URL.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rnam_example_prop2.html)

> Even though both clusters are part of
>   the same container?

I don't know what this means.  Do you mean "cell" rather than "container"?

> 2) If not, how then can I lookup the
>   said queue in Cluster 2?

Using a topology-based qualified name:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
ctx.lookup("cell/clusters/cluster2/jms/MyQueue");
```